# Check which number out of two numbers in the list can make the sum equals to k

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension, sublist

I am solving a programming problem and i am stuck at one place..

```
import itertools

N=int(input())
#finding all prime between a range
primes=[x for x in range(2, N) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
print(primes)
try:
    pairs=[min(p for p in itertools.combinations(primes, 2) if sum(p) == N)]
except:
    pairs=[(p for p in itertools.combinations(primes, 2) if sum(p) == N)]

print(*pairs)
```

in this code i want to find that least valued pair of prime numbers that can be sum up together to equalize the value of N

for ex:
case1)
if i input 74 then it returns [71,3]
although 74 can be made out even by other cobinations but there is 3 which is least among the all combinations

case2)
if i input 4
this code will return [2,3] as answer,,idk why..
and the expected answer is [2,2]..stating that only this combination is possible to get the sum equals to N

Answer (score 0):

you are getting empty generator object as response not `[2, 3]` this is list of prime numbers

Yours solution to work use [itertools.combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

```
import itertools

N = int(input())
#finding all prime between a range
primes = [x for x in range(2, N) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
print(primes)
try:
    pairs = [min(p for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(primes, 2) if sum(p) == N)]
except:
    pairs = [p for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(primes, 2) if sum(p) == N]

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3] # list of prime number for input 4
(2, 2) # solution
```